# how to verify short verification code received from twilio

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, twilio

In my app user needs to verify his phone number to complete the registration process means when the user tries to register with phone number, a verification code will be send to his device. on inserting the code, the app should allow him to register , regarding this I am using twilio as SMS gateway. Does anybody has a sample code, so that I can through the code to check how this process is going to intiate.

Comment: voted to close : `Does anybody has a sample code`

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here. There are a variety of blog posts that show you how to accomplish this around the Internet. For example:

- [A phone verification system with PHP and MySQL](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/04/build-a-simple-phone-verification-with-twilio-php-mysql-and-jquery.html)
- [Phone verification with Ruby and Rails](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/01/12/phone-verification-using-twilio.html)
- [Phone verification using JavaScript and Parse](http://shamadeh.com/blog/web/mobile/twilio/parse/2014/07/31/VerifyPhoneNumbersTwilioAndParse.html)

Or, if you want something even easier, [Authy](https://www.authy.com/developers) is a service that handles all the verification you need through just a few API calls.

Hope this helps.